# Spritekit game is skipping every time score increases

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, game-development

My SpriteKit game is skipping. I've narrowed down the problem to these pieces of code. In my `override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval)`  function I have the following check to see if my player has passed an obstacle:

```
if obstacleScoreList[0].position.y < player.position.y {
    obstacleScoreList.removeFirst()
    score += 1
```

Once the score is changed, I have the following didSet:

```
var score = 0 {
    didSet {
        let stringFromNum = String(score)
        var numList = [String]()

        for char in stringFromNum {
            numList.append(String(char))
        }

        switch numList.count {

        case 1:
            //scoreLabel3.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "num" + numList[0])
            //blurr3.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BlueNum" + numList[0])
            scoreLabel3.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "num" + numList[0])
            blurr3.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BlueNum" + numList[0])
        case 2:
            scoreLabel3.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "num" + numList[1])
            blurr3.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BlueNum" + numList[1])

            scoreLabel2.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "num" + numList[0])
            blurr2.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BlueNum" + numList[0])
        case 3:
            scoreLabel3.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "num" + numList[2])
            blurr3.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BlueNum" + numList[2])

            scoreLabel2.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "num" + numList[1])
            blurr2.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BlueNum" + numList[1])

            scoreLabel1.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "num" + numList[0])
            blurr1.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BlueNum" + numList[0])
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

My score is 3 SKSpriteNodes with another 3 SKSpriteNodes behind them. I'm just updating these spritenodes once the score is set in update. If I comment out the `score += 1`, then it runs smoothly. Any ideas?

Comment: What is being skipped? What does run smoothly?

Comment: When you say is skipping, you want to say your game has small spikes when the score changes?

Comment: each time the player passes the object and the didSet is called, the entire game (the movement of the player and obstacles) lags for a split second. It's just a tiny little hitch every time the player passes the object. The game runs smoothly if I comment out the didSet.

Comment: I'm realizing that its only the blur textures that are causing problems

Comment: place a breakpoint on the score += 1 and look at why you are hitting it twice.  I have a feeling you are adding more nodes than you think

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. I put the blurred images into a texture atlas and preloaded the images. I think the images were a lot for the game to handle until i did this.